# Sanitizing global arrays in PHP

Tags: php, security, sanitize

I'm trying to find the best way to sanitize requests in PHP.

From what I've read I learned that GET variables should be sanitized only when they're being displayed, not at the beginning of the "request flow". Post variables (which don't come from the database) either.

I can see several problems here:

Of course I can create functions sanitizing these variables, and by calling something like `Class::post('name')`, or `Class::get('name')` everything will be safe. But what if a person who will use my code in the future will forget about it and use casual `$_POST['name'`] instead of my function? Can I provide, or should I provide a bit of security here?

Answer (score 3):

There is never a one-size-fits-all sanitization. "Sanitization" means you manipulate a value to conform to certain properties. For example, you cast something that's supposed to be a number to a number. Or you strip `<script>` tags out of supposed HTML. What and how exactly to sanitize depends on what the value is supposed to be and whether you need to sanitize at all. Sanitizing HTML for whitelisted tags is really complex, for instance.

Therefore, there's no magic `Class::sanitize` which fits everything at once. Anybody using your code needs to *think* about what they're trying to do anyway. If they just blindly use `$_POST` values as is, they have already failed and need to turn in their programmer card.

What you *always* need to do is to *escape* based on the context. But since that depends on the context, you only do it where necessary. You don't blindly escape all all `$_POST` values, because you have no idea what you're escaping *for*. See [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/) for more background information on the whole topic.

Answer (score 0):

The variables are basically "sanitized" when PHP reads them. Meaning if I were to submit

```
"; exec("some evil command"); $blah="
```

Then it won't be a problem as far as PHP is concerned - you will get that literal string.

However, when passing it on from PHP to something else, it's important to make sure that "something else" won't misinterpret the string. So, if it's going into a MySQL database then you need to escape it according to MySQL rules (or use prepared statements, which will do this for you). If it's going into HTML, you need to encode `<` as `&lt;` as a minimum. If it's going into JavaScript, then you need to JSON-encode it, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this... Not foolproof, but it works..

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
  //do sanitization
  $val = Class::sanitize($val);

  $_POST[$key] = $val;
}
```

Edit: You'd want to put this as close to the header as you can get. I usually put mine in the controller so it's executed from the `__construct()` automagically.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the $_POST array with a sanitizer object which is beheaving like an array.